Can't login to finish do-release-upgrade process
I ran sudo do-release-upgrade -d inside byobu inside Gnome Terminal using Remote Desktop, to upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
It ran for a while and started asking the usual questions about whether I should update to the package maintainer's version of scripts, etc.
Now it's at the lock screen and I can't log back in to finish the process.  I enter password and it just hangs.
I was previously able to access it through byobu over ssh to answer the questions, but now when I enter byobu it looks as if there wasn't an existing session.
~> ps aux | grep release-upgrade
root       18663  0.0  0.0  14408  4352 pts/0    S+   Jun23   0:01 sudo do-release-upgrade -d
root       18664  0.0  0.0  14408  1856 pts/1    Ss   Jun23   0:00 sudo do-release-upgrade -d
root       18665  0.2  0.2 468860 44116 pts/1    Sl+  Jun23   3:20 /usr/bin/python3 -s /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ylrumsy/noble --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText --devel-release
root       27315  0.1  0.3 472584 59400 pts/1    S+   Jun23   2:04 /usr/bin/python3 -s /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-9ylrumsy/noble --mode=server --frontend=DistUpgradeViewText --devel-release

 ~> byobu list-sessions
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default

How can I finish the upgrade process without killing or rebooting anything?

[After lots of back and forth with ChatGPT I found this solution that worked over SSH.]
You can take control of the ongoing do-release-upgrade process and finish the upgrade without killing or rebooting anything by following these steps:

Download reptyr:

Since apt is locked, download the reptyr package directly:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/reptyr/reptyr_0.9.0-1_amd64.deb




Extract the Package Contents:
dpkg-deb -x reptyr_0.9.0-1_amd64.deb reptyr_contents


Use reptyr to Attach to the Shell Process that you identified with ps:

Attach to the parent process of do-release-upgrade:
sudo ./reptyr_contents/usr/bin/reptyr 18663




Interact with the Shell:

Once attached, you will not see anything initially. It is stuck at the prompt and waiting for input.  Press D when prompted to show the differences between the existing and new versions of configuration files. This will show you where you are in the process without harming anything. You can then decide to either keep the existing configurations or install the new versions.


Continue the Upgrade Process:

Respond to any further prompts and ensure the upgrade process completes successfully.


Delete the reptyr deb and unpacked files.



Thanks a lot, you do not know how much time you saved me! Small addition: I ran on a byobu session (to avoid this situation), but still ended up there. I had to add the -T option to the reptyr command in order to attach as subprocesses where involved.
